# To find dimension of $N(A) \cap R(B)$ over R

Tags: linear-algebra

To find dimension of $N(A) \cap R(B)$ over R

A = $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ -1 & 5 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$

B=$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2  \\ -1 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

i tried to find out explicitely expression for linear transformation but i couldnot reach anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x,y,z)\in N(A)$ then $$\begin{cases}x+2y & = & 0 \\
-x+5y+2z & = & 0\end{cases}$$

If $(x,y,z)\in R(B)$ then, there exist $a,b$ such that $$\begin{cases}x & = & a+2b \\
y& = & -a \\ z & = & 3a+b\end{cases}$$

Writing the expression for $x,y,z$ in the first system we get $a=2b.$ That is, $$(4b,-2b,7b)\in N(A)\cap R(B),\forall b\in \mathbb{R}.$$ So, the dimension of the intersection is one.

We can check it easily:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ -1 & 5 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 4b \\ -2b \\ 7b \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2  \\ -1 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2b \\ b  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 4b \\ -2b \\ 7b \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I think answer is 1

Comment: Yes. If I am not wrong you should get $-a+2b=0.$ So, $a=2b,$ and you can write $(x,y,z)$ in terms of one parameter. That is, the dimension is one.

Comment: yes but my textbook states 0. Are you sure ?

Comment: I am sure. I have edited the answer to show it.